# Protocol Buffers - @ModelAttribute

Tags: java, spring-boot, protocol-buffers

I am sending Protocol Buffer object in post request, but on the other side I am not able to get object since generated class (Protocol Buffer) does not have empty constructor. So it is unable to construct @ModelAttribute.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/path", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public string saveInvoice(@ModelAttribute(value = "person") ModelProtos.Person person) {
  ...
}
```

Any advice?

Notice I am able to return Protocol Buffer object.

Comment: protobuf is meant to be serialized to/from binary data. Do you have a custom `HttpMessageConverter` that produces binary data (like [`ProtobufHttpMessageConverter`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/protobuf/ProtobufHttpMessageConverter.html)) or how do you use them?

Comment: yes, I am using ProtobufHttpMessageConverter. It is registered as bean in configuation of spring-boot

Comment: Use `RequestBody` instead of `ModelAttribute` those things are quite different.

Comment: Thx, it works with @RequestBody.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To transform a body you need to use [`@RequestBody`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestBody.html) that is also the mechanism that use the `HttpMessageConverter`s.

The [`@ModelAttribute`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ModelAttribute.html) is for the case when you submit regular forms or request parameters and want to bind that to an object.

There is also a [blog entry](https://spring.io/blog/2015/03/22/using-google-protocol-buffers-with-spring-mvc-based-rest-services) about this, although a bit dated as it doesn't use the auto config but rather "manual" but still informative.